# How to wait under UITests in Xcode until some view will be visible for tap?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

Sometimes under UITests in Xcode the compiler try to tap the button before it is loaded and presented. Then arise a problem like `no matched found for...`.

But the simple solution for this is:

```
sleep(1) //wait 1 second and give `mybutton` time to load and be accessible for uitests
mybutton.tap()
```

But this is horrible since I cannot put there `0.1` as a parameter. And it makes me annoying to wait 1 second before a lot of buttons.

**Is there a way to wait until it is visible for uitests?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should create an [XCTestExpectation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xctestexpectation) and wait for it to be fulfilled

```
expectationForPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "hittable == true"), evaluatedWithObject: mybutton, handler: nil)
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(10.0, handler: nil)

mybutton.tap()
```

Comment: For Swift 3 you can leave `handler` parameters.